# how can I say if it is found any of the words on the text?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if contains any of the words on the text `console.log(1)` or `console.log(2)` for false , but however I am getting `1,2,1,2` because it is matching , and some failing , but I want if contain only one word from the given words then `ok` , but if not false , but I am getting true , false

```js
var keywords = ['aslr', 'ida pro', 'gdb', 'windbg', 'immunity debugger', 'boofuzz', 'peach fuzzer', 'winafl', 'python', 'assembly', 'penetration testing', 'exploits', 'metasploit', 'metasploit framework', 'ethical hacker', 'pentest', 'computer security', 'hacking', 'oscp', 'osce', 'osee', 'penetration testing', 'offensive security', 'mitre att&ck', 'vulnerability research', 'vulnerability researcher', 'fuzzing', 'clang', 'llvm', 'address sanitizer', 'afl', 'fuzzers', 'penetration tester']

var data = "a successful cybersecurity consultancy are seeking an experienced penetration tester to join their melbourne practice on a permanent basis. work across a wide portfolio of clients and help them in identifying security vulnerabilities by conducting web application, network security, and wireless penetration testing. key responsibilities/duties: work with a diverse range of customers to identify and solve security problems, both in-person and remotely undertake application, network, and wireless penetration testing and vulnerability assessments prepare high-quality reports detailing security issues, making recommendations and identifying solutions perform social engineering and physical security assessments and/or undertake secure code reviews, where appropriate key requirements: demonstrated experience in penetration testing penetration testing certifications such as oscp, osce, ceh, sans, crest crt or cct a proven passion for cybersecurity with regular attendance at security events and/or memberships to the likes of owasp understanding of information security principles and security technologies 2 + years' work experience in security what the company can offer you: ongoing one-on-one training and development a budget for training courses/certifications flexible working arrangements and the option to work-from-home the opportunity to work in a collaborative environment with experienced security professionals if this position sounds of interest, please click 'apply' or email your cv directly to charlotte@preactarecruitment.com."

for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i += 1) {
  if (data.indexOf(keywords[i])) {
    console.log(1)
  }
  console.log(2)
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question/problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of logging inside your loop, use a general variable to calculate your matches, then check the variable.

For example:

```
let matches = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i += 1) {
    // Note that indexOf returns -1 on failure, not false or zero
    if (data.indexOf(keywords[i]) !== -1) {
        matches++;
    }
}

if(matches) {
    console.log(1);
}
else {
    console.log(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in combination with [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to check if a word in `keywords` is in `data` and then log your desired output:

```js
var keywords = ['aslr', 'ida pro', 'gdb', 'windbg', 'immunity debugger', 'boofuzz', 'peach fuzzer', 'winafl', 'python', 'assembly', 'penetration testing', 'exploits', 'metasploit', 'metasploit framework', 'ethical hacker', 'pentest', 'computer security', 'hacking', 'oscp', 'osce', 'osee', 'penetration testing', 'offensive security', 'mitre att&ck', 'vulnerability research', 'vulnerability researcher', 'fuzzing', 'clang', 'llvm', 'address sanitizer', 'afl', 'fuzzers', 'penetration tester'];
var data = "a successful cybersecurity consultancy are seeking an experienced penetration tester to join their melbourne practice on a permanent basis. work across a wide portfolio of clients and help them in identifying security vulnerabilities by conducting web application, network security, and wireless penetration testing. key responsibilities/duties: work with a diverse range of customers to identify and solve security problems, both in-person and remotely undertake application, network, and wireless penetration testing and vulnerability assessments prepare high-quality reports detailing security issues, making recommendations and identifying solutions perform social engineering and physical security assessments and/or undertake secure code reviews, where appropriate key requirements: demonstrated experience in penetration testing penetration testing certifications such as oscp, osce, ceh, sans, crest crt or cct a proven passion for cybersecurity with regular attendance at security events and/or memberships to the likes of owasp understanding of information security principles and security technologies 2 + years' work experience in security what the company can offer you: ongoing one-on-one training and development a budget for training courses/certifications flexible working arrangements and the option to work-from-home the opportunity to work in a collaborative environment with experienced security professionals if this position sounds of interest, please click 'apply' or email your cv directly to charlotte@preactarecruitment.com.";

if (keywords.some(word => data.includes(word))) console.log(1);
else console.log(2);
```

Comment: May be you missed this line from question mate, `I want if contain only one word from the given words then ok`, otherwise this is good way to solve IMO

Comment: @CodeManiac but they also say "I am trying to check if contains any of the words on the text console.log(1)" in the beginning.

Comment: if i read it again `I am trying to check if contains any of the words on the text console.log(1) or console.log(2) for false , but however I am getting 1,2,1,2 because it is matching , and some failing , but I want if contain only one word from the given words then ok , but if not false , but I am getting true , false` as far as i understand it is meaning to to print true only if one word matches. anyways i am leaving it on OP to clarify

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to check the number of keyword found, since you want only one, if the value of count goes beyond `1` break out of loop and display value accordingly

```js
var keywords = ['aslr', 'ida pro', 'gdb', 'windbg', 'immunity debugger', 'boofuzz', 'peach fuzzer', 'winafl', 'python', 'assembly', 'penetration testing', 'exploits', 'metasploit', 'metasploit framework', 'ethical hacker', 'pentest', 'computer security', 'hacking', 'oscp', 'osce', 'osee', 'penetration testing', 'offensive security', 'mitre att&ck', 'vulnerability research', 'vulnerability researcher', 'fuzzing', 'clang', 'llvm', 'address sanitizer', 'afl', 'fuzzers','penetration tester']
var data = "a successful cybersecurity consultancy are seeking an experienced penetration tester to join their melbourne practice on a permanent basis. work across a wide portfolio of clients and help them in identifying security vulnerabilities by conducting web application, network security, and wireless penetration testing. key responsibilities/duties: work with a diverse range of customers to identify and solve security problems, both in-person and remotely undertake application, network, and wireless penetration testing and vulnerability assessments prepare high-quality reports detailing security issues, making recommendations and identifying solutions perform social engineering and physical security assessments and/or undertake secure code reviews, where appropriate key requirements: demonstrated experience in penetration testing penetration testing certifications such as oscp, osce, ceh, sans, crest crt or cct a proven passion for cybersecurity with regular attendance at security events and/or memberships to the likes of owasp understanding of information security principles and security technologies 2 + years' work experience in security what the company can offer you: ongoing one-on-one training and development a budget for training courses/certifications flexible working arrangements and the option to work-from-home the opportunity to work in a collaborative environment with experienced security professionals if this position sounds of interest, please click 'apply' or email your cv directly to charlotte@preactarecruitment.com."

let matchCount = 0
for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i += 1) {
  if (data.includes(keywords[i])) {
    matchCount++
  }
  if (matchCount > 1) break
}

console.log(matchCount === 1 ? 1 : 2)
```